# Install latest version of TexLive [2021] on Debian/ChromeOS?

Tags: texlive, updating, debian, texlive-2019, texlive-2021

`sudo apt install texlive-full` installs the 2019 version. Using the `tlmgr` and `update-tlmgr-latest.sh` I tried to get it to version 2021 but failed.

```
$ tex --version
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian)
kpathesa version 6.3.1/dev
Copyright 2018 D.E. Knuth.
...
```

Is there any way to install the 2021 version directly? I cannot seem to find any way how to do it...

Comment: do not use `sudo apt` to install TL. Download the installer and install it directly! (as root). It should install it to `\usr\local\bin`

Comment: where would I find it?

Comment: There are instructions on the internet [here](https://12000.org/my_notes/faq/LATEX/htch3.htm#x4-400003.31)  it is for old version, but they work the same for each version. I followed them before and they work each time.  Just remember to be root when you run the installer.

Comment: It installed the 2019 version...

Comment: That is not possible. They have TL 2021 there.  Did you change/update your `$PATH` to point to TL 2021 as it says?? How do you know which Latex you are using? Do `which lualatex` for example.

Comment: Path is pointing to `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH` and i am using luatex
`tex --version` confirms it is version 2019.

Comment: OK, looks good. So you are using TL 2021 then. What is the problem?  Just make sure to edit your .bashrc and put `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/` in the path. These instructions are actually displayed to you at end of installation. Make sure to follow them as is.  This is what I have `export PATH=.:/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:` etc... Make it first so it finds TL 2021. Need to restart the terminal (close it and open a new terminal to have the new PATH take effect)

Comment: Edit: I had a typo..... works now thank you :)

Comment: @Nasser, placing `.` at the beginning of `PATH` is a *very* bad idea. In this specific case, instead of messing with `PATH` you could define shell aliases for the commands with the full path...

Comment: @Nasser The link you provided for instructions is not functional. Can you provide an alternative?

Comment: @Amsterdam6483  Try [this](https://12000.org/my_notes/faq/LATEX/html_and_latexchapter3.htm#x4-410003.32)  it is for older version of TL, but same instructions still apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rather old version of TeX, and I suggest installing the original TeX Live from TUG. For this, the following steps are necessary:

## 1. Installation of TeX Live from TUG

See https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Get the installer from https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz and unpack it. Then run the included `install-tl`. It will ask you several questions about installation location etc.

This will be a user install, which we recommend (see the quickinstall page).

## 2. Add the TeX Live binary directory to the PATH

This depends on your shell, but mostly means adding it to either `.profile` or `.bashrc` or `.login` or `.bash_login` or any of the files that are read.

After having updated your login files, log out and log in again.

## 3. Integration with Debian

This is not strictly necessary unless you want to get rid of the TeX Live installed by Debian, mostly due to disk space reasons.

See https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html section "Integrating vanilla TeX Live with Debian"